# Wanted to get rid of Paragrapgh tag in submit buttom of the WordPress form

Tags: functions, comment-form

```
function modify_comment_form_fields($fields){
  // Check if $fields is an array
  if (!is_array($fields)) {
      return $fields;
  }

  ob_start();
  $submit_button = ob_get_clean();
  $submit_button .= '<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment">';
  // Check if $submit_button is a string
  if (!is_string($submit_button)) {
      return $fields;
  }

  $fields['submit_field'] = $submit_button;
  return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_submit_field', 'modify_comment_form_fields');
```

The submit button is wrapped under the `p` tag inside a WordPress comment form.

I wanted to get rid of this → `<p class="form-submit"></p>`

But the solution didn't work, Can someone help me to take this further in troubleshooting?

Currently, In browser the output of submit button is rendered as this one →

```
<p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment"> <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="8" id="comment_post_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</p>
```

Update The comment form looks like this →

```
    $fields = array(
  'heading_tag' => '<h6>Leave an opinion</h6>',
  'comment_field' => '<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Your opinion matters, but do not spam us!" required></textarea>',
  'author' => '<input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter Full Name" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" required>',
  'email'  => '<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email ID" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" required>'
  
);

$comment_args = array(
  'title_reply'        => '',
  'fields'             => $fields,
  'comment_field'      => $fields['comment_field'],
  'class_submit'       => 'submit',
  'label_submit'       => 'Post Comment',
  'class_form'         => 'comform'
);


comment_form($comment_args);
```

Comment: That looks OK to me, except for the fields-as-an-array check at the beginning. It won't be. What's that for? The comment_form_submit_field hook accepts a string (plus the comment form args) and should return a string too, which you're not doing.

Comment: Also the ob_start(), ob_get_clean() is useless, since you're not echoing anything between the two statements.

Comment: I assume you control the theme, though? It would be simpler to just pass in the submit_field argument to comment_form() rather than trying to filter it afterwards.

Comment: Update the snipped also gave comment form structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the theme the simplest way to fix this is passing the submit_field argument into comment_form():

```php
comment_form(
    array(
        'submit_field' => '%1$s %2$s',
    )
);
```

> Default: `<p class="form-submit">%1$s %2$s</p>`, where %1$s is the submit button markup and %2$s is the comment hidden fields.

which removes the `<p>` altogether. However it might be useful to wrap the button and hidden fields in a div instead, e.g. `'submit_field' => '<div class="form-submit">%1$s %2$s</div>'`.

As above the problem with your code is you've got the filter input and output arguments wrong: comment_form_submit_field has inputs $submit_field (string), $args (array), and should return a string.

Comment: I was wondering with complicated solution, It was so nice, crisp and simple solution form you. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail → As above the problem with your code is you've got the filter input and output arguments wrong: comment_form_submit_field has inputs $submit_field (string), $args (array), and should return a string.